# Building Xcode UITest fails with `error opening input file`

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I added a UITest target to my existing Xcode project.

Recording a UITest works fine.
But running the same recorded UITest fails during build with error:

```
Compile Swift source files
Precompile bridging header
<unknown>:0: error: error opening input file '/Users/<...>/Bridging-Header.h' (No such file or directory)
```

The path is correct and the file exists at the path.

- Tried to add the file to the target, but I cannot add it to any target because the checkboxes are greyed out.
- Tried to clean the build folder and delete the derived data folder, same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The solution was to change the path to the `Bridging Header` file.

1. Select the test target, e.g. `MyAppUITests`
2. Navigate to `Build Settings` > `Swift Compiler - General` > `Objective-C Bridging Header`.
3. Replace the existing path to your header file, e.g. `MyApp/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h` with `./MyApp/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h`. Adding the `.` will allow the test target to find the header file.